# Linux: Creating Network Bridge Drops NIC speed to 100MB/s instead of 1000MB/s

Tags: linux, arch-linux, virt-manager

I am running Arch Linux 64 bit on my desktop.  I use Virt-manager to run a windows guest. My host has two NICs, both are Gigabit, both get gigabit speeds when dedicated to only the host.

Whenever I use Virt-Manager to create a Bridged device from one of these nics, it creates a bridge device, and drops my NIC to 100/MB for some reason.  If I try removing the bridge, and restarting the NIC, then manually changing the speed using:

```
sudo ethtool -s enpxx speed 1000 duplex full
```

the nic will not reconnect and ethool shows:

```
Link detected: no.
```

At that point the only way to get the nic back is to restart.

So I tried manually [creating a bridge](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_bridge) with the same result.  I get a new device Br0, but my nic drops down to 100/MB (within the host and guest).  If I then manually delete the bridge, shut the device down, and manually set it to the right speed it will function again.

How can I create a bridge either manually or with Virt-Manager so that my NIC stays at Gigabit?  What is happening here?

*Edit*

Creating Network Bridge

```
ip addr flush dev eth0
ip link add name br0 type bridge
ip link set br0 up
ip link set eth0 up
ip link set eth0 master br0
bridge link
ip addr add dev bridge_name 10.x.x.x/24
```

At that point I pass the bridge to virt-manager with the following settings.

```
Bridge Name: Bridge device name
Device Model: virtio
```

I have also tried just passing through the nic in virt manager with the following settings.

```
Host Device eth0: macvtap
Source mode: Bridge
Device: virtio
```

Either have the same result of the nic dropping down to 100MB/s.

Chipset:

```
Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
```

Comment: Do you use Network Manager?

Comment: No, dhcpcd with static profiles.

Comment: Please, show how do you create the bridge and join interfaces. Also show physical interface chipset.

Comment: Added in edits.

Comment: Do you try create bridge via `brctl` command? And what show `dmesg`?

Comment: I did try with brctl as well, same thing.  You want a dmesg of the time during bridge creation?

Comment: Yes. During bridge creation.

Comment: Also try enable STP on the bridge interface.

Comment: 100 MB/s is the maximum speed on a 1 Gbe connection. Perhaps you meant 100 Mb/s, but that's slower by a factor of x10.